# Javascript arrow function unexpected token on if condition

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, unexpected-token

Can somebody tell me please what is wrong with this arrow function. It throws me an error

> unexpected token on begin of if condition

```
selected_devices
  .map( device => if( device.device_id === device_id ) device.source = 'included' )
```

Comment: You need {} when you have an if or other things that are not a single statement - also do NOT use map if you want forEach

Comment: This is definitely not a proper use-case for `.map()`

Comment: Perhaps you meant `selected_devices.forEach( device => device.source = device.device_id === device_id  ? 'included' : device.source)`

Comment: @mplungjan Why should I not to use map()? Dont understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `{}` when you have an `if` or other things that are not a single statement - also do NOT use map if you want forEach since map creates an unnecessary array you then throw away

```
selected_devices
  .forEach(device => device.source = device.device_id === device_id  ? 'included' : device.source)
```

or perhaps

```
selected_devices
  .filter( device => device.device_id === device_id)
  .forEach(device => device.source = 'included')
```

Comment: Can you tell me why not map?

Comment: Map creates an unnecessary array you then throw away

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forgot to add brackets like this

```
selected_devices.map((device) => {
   if (device.device_id === device_id) device.source = 
   'included'
   return device
})
```

But you can also do with the ternary operator like this

```
selected_devices.map((device) =>
   device.device_id === device_id ? { ...device, device.source: 
   'included' } : device,
)
```

Comment: Brackets work with return, but it should not be necessary.

Comment: @Čamo You need brackets if you want to use "if" because you can use if statements only in code blocks. If you don't want to use brackets and/or a return statement you can use the ternary operator.